# How to design different message Toasts in one sapui5 project?

Tags: css, sapui5, message

I want to display a different design message toasts in one project,
How can I addStyleClass for each messageToast instance ?
For example:

[image]
[image]

I try to add an id or class for each different design but it didn't work:

```
success: function (oResp) {
                            sap.m.MessageToast.show(sSuccess, {
                                id: "tryingWell"
                            });
                        },
```

Any idea ??

Comment: If it is just for one project you could overwrite the standard CSS. I don't think you can add style classes.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good way to design a MessageToast in sapui5:
Example of template:

Controller:

```
   success: function (oResp) {
    sap.m.MessageToast.show(sSuccess);
                                                $(".sapMMessageToast").addClass("messageSuccess");
   },
```

Css:

```
.messageSuccess {
    background: black !important;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
```